# How to take child of child value and collect as a map with Java Stream operator

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the below class.

```
Class Person {
    String value1;
    List<KeyValue> keyValue;
}
Class KeyValue{
    String key;
    String value;
}
```

I want output map as `Map<String, String>` where first string value - **Key is keyValue.getValue()** which will be always unique and second string value - **value is value1**.

I can simply iterate and do the performance but is there any way to do this with Stream operator and make code readable format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `KeyValue` for a given `Person`, create a map entry. Then use the `flatMap` operator to flatten all of those streams into one large stream. Finally, collect it into a map using the `toMap` collector. Given that the value returned by `KeyValue.getValue` is always unique (according to your problem statement), no key conflicts may occur. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<String, String> keyToPersonMap = people.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> p.getKeyValue().stream()
            .map(kv -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(kv.getValue(), p.getValue1())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```